# Woocommerce "update_checkout" not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

My update_cart trigger is not working at all...when i add "blur" in function instead of "change" then it trigger okay in chrome,opera,ie..but dont trigger on firefox and safari at all...i tried almost everything...i have plugin that add discount 5% on bacs payment..so i had to calculate subtotal before shipping cost...for example...subtotal of products - discount = then if its under 1000 shipping is not free..but on cheque payment method it doesnt need to give discount and that works all okay..but when i want to update_checkout on change it wont work..

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_packages', function( $packages ) {
    $session_data = WC()->session->get_session_data();
    //error_log(print_r($session_data,true));
    $cart_totals = maybe_unserialize( $session_data['cart_totals'] );
    $payment_method = 'bacs';
    $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');
    $sub_total_after_item_discount = $cart_totals['subtotal'] + $cart_totals['fee_total'];
    
    if( $payment_method == $chosen_payment_method && $sub_total_after_item_discount < 1000){
        $free_shipping_id = 'free_shipping:7';
        unset($packages[0]['rates'][ $free_shipping_id ]);
    } elseif ($payment_method == $chosen_payment_method && $sub_total_after_item_discount > 1000) {
        $flat_rate = 'flat_rate:6';
        unset($packages[0]['rates'][ $flat_rate ]);
    }
    return $packages;
} );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_packages', function( $packages ) {
    $session_data = WC()->session->get_session_data();
    //error_log(print_r($session_data,true));
    $cart_totals = maybe_unserialize( $session_data['cart_totals'] );
    $payment_method = 'cheque';
    $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');
    $sub_total_after_item_discount = $cart_totals['total'] + $cart_totals['fee_total'];
    
    if( $payment_method == $chosen_payment_method && $sub_total_after_item_discount < 1000){
        $free_shipping_id = 'free_shipping:7';
        unset($packages[0]['rates'][ $free_shipping_id ]);
    } elseif ($payment_method == $chosen_payment_method && $sub_total_after_item_discount > 1000) {
        $flat_rate = 'flat_rate:6';
        unset($packages[0]['rates'][ $flat_rate ]);
    }
    return $packages;
} );
```

And this is my update_trigger function

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'osvjezi_metodu_placanja' );
function osvjezi_metodu_placanja(){
    // jQuery kod
   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'input[name^="payment_method"]', function() {
                $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                //console.log('blur', true);});
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
   <?php
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you click on your first payment method, the page will refresh, and then your data will be reset. You simply inspect the value of your first input field and set it to the IF condition. i have added the screenshot, you can follow it

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'osvjezi_metodu_placanja' );
function osvjezi_metodu_placanja(){
    // jQuery kod
   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'input[name^="payment_method"]', function() {
                $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                var currentVal = $(this).val();
                // You first inspect the payment method and set the value in the if condition. 'bacs'
                // https://prnt.sc/FQ95JyoN8mXA
                if(currentVal == 'set value'){
                    location.reload(true);
                }
                console.log(currentVal);
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
   <?php
}
```

Comment: but it wont change to bacs at all..after reload..is there any way to set it to default after refreshing page..

Comment: when i set value to bacs..it just keep refreshing

Comment: The static value will come after the page is refreshed, but the preview value is not working here.

Comment: Inspect your site and set the first value input field to whatever it is, otherwise the page refresh won't work.

Comment: By default of my webpage..if i last time cheked cheque and want to go back to bacs it will always keep me on cheque..be ause it remember last time checked option

Comment: I think i need a function that always set bacs on payment checkout..not to remember last time cheked option..

Comment: please replace with this just if condition:-

                if(currentVal == 'bacs'){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        location.reload(true);

                    },2000);
                }